# boxmuller C++ implementation

Tags: c++

This is my boxmuller code. I would like to know is there any way to make it faster? because I'm doing Monte Carlo Pricing need to simulate 1 million times.

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
double BoxMuller()
{
    
    double x = static_cast<double> (rand()) / RAND_MAX;
    double y = static_cast<double> (rand()) / RAND_MAX;
    double z = sqrt(-2.0 * log(x)) * cos(2 * M_PI * y);

    return z;
}
```

Comment: First you need to have a correct implementation and using `rand` for simulation is not that.

Comment: @PasserBy why? Because I can run it in my CLion

Comment: It is almost guaranteed to produce incorrect results. There are endless articles on why it is so, you can search for them.

Comment: So, did you try running this 1m times? I expect it to be fast enough, especially in a release build.

Comment: The Standard C++library offers a whole host of [random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that are better (and faster?) than the old-fashioned `rand()`. These can also return values of the correct type and in the correct range.

Comment: Also, from what I understand, the Box-Muller transform should return a **pair** of values, like a `std::pair<double, double>`.

Comment: The overhead of invoking a function 1M times may outweigh the cost of the trivial code that runs inside it.  Depends on how well the compiler or linker can inline it. So if you're invoking this in a tight loop somewhere else, the implementation may be trivial enough to convert to a macro or just reference the code directly where you need it.

Comment: How about precomputing random values? Or you could use curand, if they have to be created (with different seeds) at runtime.